# matplotlib: how to change colors, make little spaces and edit the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to draw some lines in matplotlib.  I have tried to make the points be shown with transparent circles rather than the standard solid filled in circles.

1. How can I make the circles be the same color as the lines?
2. How can I remove the circles from the ends of the dashed lines in the legend? Currently you can hardly see the dashed lines.
3. How can I make a little gap before and after each circle in the graph so the dashed lines don't touch them. I think this would look better here as I only have data at the points so the lines in between don't represent real data.

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   t = np.array([0.19641715476064042,
   0.25,
   0.34,
   0.42])

   c  = np.array([0.17,
   0.21,
   0.27,
   0.36])

   plt.plot(t, '-go', markerfacecolor='w', linestyle= 'dashed', label='n=20')
   plt.plot(c, '-bo',  markerfacecolor='w', linestyle= 'dashed', label='n=22') 
   plt.show()
   ```

This is what the matplotlib code currently gives me.

[image]

This is what I would like it to ultimately look like (clearly with different data).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware that you seem to misuse the *fmt* format string (like `"-go"`) in your calls to `plot`. In fact for a dashed line *fmt* should be more something like `"--go"`.
I personally tend to find the use of keyword arguments clearer even if more verbose (in your case, `linestyle="dashed"` prevails on *fmt* string)

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot

Anyway, below a tentative to reproduce the desired plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.array([0.19641715476064042,
              0.25, 0.34, 0.42])
c = np.array([0.17, 0.21, 0.27, 0.36])

def my_plot(ax, tab, c="g", ls="-", marker="o", ms=6, mfc="w", mec="g", label="",
            zorder=2):
    """
    tab: array to plot
    c: line color (default green)
    ls: linestyle (default solid line)
    marker: kind of marker
    ms: markersize
    mfc: marker face color
    mec: marker edge color
    label: legend label
    """
    ax.plot(tab, c=c, ms=0, ls=ls, label=label, zorder=zorder-0.02)
    ax.plot(tab, c=c, marker=marker, ms=ms, mec=mec, mfc=mfc, ls="none",
            zorder=zorder)
    ax.plot(tab, c=c, marker=marker, ms=ms*4, mfc="w", mec="w", ls="none",
            zorder=zorder-0.01)


my_plot(plt, t, c="g", mec="g", ls="dashed", label="n=20")
my_plot(plt, c, c="b", mec="b", ls="dashed", label="n=22")

plt.legend(loc=2) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also consider reading the *legend guide* in the official documentation:
http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html?highlight=legend%20guide

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you use the `markeredgecolor` attribute:

```
plt.plot(t, '-go', markerfacecolor='w', markeredgecolor='g', linestyle= 'dotted', label='n=20')
plt.plot(c, '-bo', markerfacecolor='w', markeredgecolor='b', linestyle= 'dotted', label='n=22')
```

As for the third question, I have no idea. I don't think there is an *easy* way to do this. But I guess you could, for example, do the following:

1. Plot the line
2. Plot solid white markers that are slightly larger than those you have now (edge and face color white). These will mask out parts of the line around the real markers.
3. Plot the real markers using the required color.

Comment: Thanks for solving the first question!